# Can I using Google Sheet API only with API Key or using Client ID and Client secret, but without client_secret.json?

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

In this provided Python code in this [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python#configure_the_sample), it using **credentials.json** such in this line:

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
```

I have enabled the Sheet and Drive API. I created credentials from the **APIs & Services** menu, then on the **Credentials** tab, click on the **CREATE CREDENTIALS** button, then click on the **OAuth client ID**, and on the **Application type** I selected the **Desktop app**, then I download its JSON file, then set the **credentials.json** file to the right path, like this:

`flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secret_274233513361-l7vpffd7g9oree4tg5tledq9keqrevk3.apps.googleusercontent.com.json', SCOPES)`

Then, when I run the quickstart code above, **it shows a new browser pop-up that requires me to log in**. After successfully login, yea, I can run the Python code successfully without any error.

But I don't want a new pop-up that requires me to log in first.

So my question:
Can I use Google Sheet API only with my credentials **Client ID and Client secret**
[image]

or only with **API Key**

[image]

If we can do it, how to do it? is there any documentation on how to achieve that?

Comment: Can I confirm your current situation? In your current situation, you are using your downloaded JSON file for OAuth2 to `/home/myuser/token.json` of `creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('/home/myuser/token.json', SCOPES)`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, what file did you use at `credentials.json` of `flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)`? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, pardon me, I have edited my question, yes what I mean actually is `flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)`, not `creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)`, pardon me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that `/home/myuser/token.json` was created by running the quickstart script. If my understanding is correct, after 2nd run, the access token is retrieved from the refresh token in `token.json`. About `But I don't want a new pop-up that requires me to log in first.`, when OAuth2 is used, it is required to authorize the scopes by the browser. If you don't want to use the browser, how about using the service account? When the service account is used, the access token can be retrieved without using the browser.

Comment: And, when you use an API key, in this case, the API key can access only the public contents. So, it is required to publicly share the Spreadsheet. And also, the API key can be used for only the GET method. By this, for example, the value cannot be put into Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

Comment: About `is there any documentation on how to achieve that?`, if you need the sample script for using Sheets API with the service account, how about these threads? https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpython%5d%20%5bgoogle-sheets-api%5d%20service%20account I thought that the threads in Stackoverflow will be useful. If my comments were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you for your comment, it gives me more insight one step forward about my question, "write on Google Spreadsheet without browser authorization". I already take a look at some tutorials about the Google service account and creating it by myself. But so far I only found using a service account we must create a spreadsheet manually, then drop the service account email on a spreadsheet share button, right like that?, if so, can we create a spreadsheet using a service account?

Comment: Service accounts are like regular accounts in some ways, such as having their own Drives. So using a service account to create a spreadsheet will create it for itself. Your options here are to [delegate domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) to the account so it can act on behalf of your domain users, or you can share the folder where you want to create the spreadsheets with the service account and then create them there and share them with other users. It depends on what your end goal is.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Tanaike and Daniel. You are comments are knowledgeable, I'm experimenting now with the Google Service Account. So, how to convert your comment into an answer?, or can you make an answer then I will mark it as correct?

Comment: Thank you for replying. If the discussion was useful for your situation, I'm glad. About `So, how to convert your comment into an answer?, or can you make an answer then I will mark it as correct?`, thank you for your proposal. But, now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect both the existing discussions and answers. Or, if you have your own answer, how about posting it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tanaike suggests, I use the Google Service Account instead. It doesn't require me to login into a browser pop-up anymore. I can access private and public spreadsheets, not only public sheets if using API like mentioned by @daimto.

On how to create the service account and get the JSON file you can follow the instruction on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74901976/8070090).

For example to create a new spreadsheet I use this code:

```
from apiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

def create_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_title)
    scopes = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
        ]


    # Open the JSON file that you have downloaded from the service account, and paste it here.
    service_account_json_credentials = {
          "type": "service_account",
          "project_id": "odoo-spreadsheet-371808",
          "private_key_id": "321ee08baexample6ae125918examplea69ddbec64",
          "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQDIzR5iPZEQqjDh\nFJlSfQOd0wJfwbgHt+V3gosd2zT5FV8gBHfZXqEz0Nd+nFqOSebI2XxwpF99tOXo\n+PR+tetOGkY5wP8LE1GVZstyyDa/xQp7eE82Yexample9mAsDwpgEt9MQ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\nUeOBDoxUJZexampleGhOjGUjg+pTAFYjbfkBOxAupZegnyrzhRvK6pT\ns13gfZQz2lUE6dWErQfYT6VUeQKBgQDa6sTd+cnSRvgkuc5ogEQy9oZrnhfXMVZv\nPdp6pkKVZLMbl86AH4iK7ejEAuITWyWqWxJSKEZW+2QZRnEUhIva0YexampleCKaVXQsbE+jbfijdJFgNq1F6hi7yeKmSmTT5SNlecUrnjGpsqhPPZ99O8nUEZZ9v\nnjyEHOu3KwKBgGlSGBHBQMM/RwjtZXp8UePyI6Ji4fCKIb4hk9am+5h6qbfg9jqO\n71buEq+rpOb/wsKHNHFHmcL6J2J5WMuRQzy4nMKFWLQHuQ2G9IiAfegxwOqy4lgi\nW+3wdE4WyptQhfMGfbmIR4j71viCGlSOiBXP3bBgRm/8vdNTlMg1+Q7pAoGBAI8O\nuiXA1RV30TLWxT7fCzIujbsH7dZvZGd/iSV7Pqm3y5+tfYGWmbkexampleaL9UppMkrkjvxPh95sM6h4ahM1dnCaHHVAqvoP9QnxnZ1CKGuIamqxEUpes7V\nFZwN8hZYfLWBug5WumlgHLrPkI6WBjF/u1YuPA9PAoGAYg7GUkefdLyc8O5u20dm\n8AzGEzsWlJh2cEqJ1iYmOS42s9jw7fxQUbIH9K1UWORIShdQTxZilRDGvfbSqWH5\nLSjr8j0iR7WlvB9KxrSSAnKtt+vkdJz8YqL6/XzogG/C+ruh8f5T8wPNPh6tDtcj\n2Z/gZ6cOD8dVrDTFQebdrMI=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
          "client_email": "odoo12@odoo-spreadsheet-371808.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
          "client_id": "101569example94608",
          "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
          "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
          "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
          "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/odoo12%40odoo-spreadsheet-371808.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        }

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_json_credentials, scopes=scopes)
    spreadsheet_service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

    spreadsheet = {
        'properties': {
            'title': spreadsheet_title
        }
        }
    creation_response = spreadsheet_service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet, fields='spreadsheetId').execute()

    spreadsheet_id = creation_response.get('spreadsheetId')
    return spreadsheet_id
    
create_spreadsheet('a new apreadsheet')
```

Hope this can help someone who facing a similar or wants to achieve the same things. Again, thank you to @Tanaike and everyone that has been taking your time to shed some light on the case I'm facing.

Comment: I hope that is not a real private key you have posted here. If so, you should disable it immediately.

Comment: Actually I have edited the key with some `example` words @andrewJames, thanks for your care.

Answer (score 1):

open the credentials.jsom file it contains your clie id and client secret.

In order to access private user data you need the users permission.

If the sheet is set to public and you only need read access then yes you could use an api key.

However if the sheet is private you need permission.

my question is do you own this sheet if you the developer own the sheet you could use a service account which would mean you won't need to request authorization.

If this is a sheet owned by a user of your application then you need to use Oauth2 to request permission of the user to access it this requires the client id and client secret.