# How to give permission to Google Spreadsheet created by Service Account?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

I created a Google Service Account with this step:

1. Open this link: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=MyProject
2. Click on **CREATE CREDENTIALS** button, then select **Service account**
3. Fill the **Service account details** field like this. And then **CREATE AND CONTINUE**
   [image]
4. On the **Grant this service account access to project**, click **+ADD ROLE**, then I select **Quick Access -> Basic -> Owner**, then **CONTINUE**

[image]

5. On the **Grant users access to this service account**, I fill it in with my normal email address. Then click on the **DONE** button.

[image]

Now I have something like this on my Service Accounts list:

[image]

6. Click on the service accounts, then go to the **PERMISSIONS** tab, then click on the **GRANT ACCESS** button:

[image]

7. **Add principals** with my email address, and I set the role as **Service Account Admin**, then **SAVE**.

[image]

8. Now click on the **KEYS** tab, then click on **ADD KEY** dropdown, and select **Create new key**

[image]

9. **CREATE** the key as **JSON** type.
10. After the JSON file gets downloaded I put it on my code path. And the code that I running is code from Google Spreadsheet API documentation to create a new spreadsheet, here is the snippet of the code:

```
    def create(title):
        creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('odoo-spreadsheet-371808-7186d4c03b4c.json',
                                                                      scopes=SCOPES)
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
        spreadsheet = {
            'properties': {
                'title': title
            },
        }
        spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet)
        response = spreadsheet.execute()
        print('response', response)
        print('spreadsheetId:', response.get('spreadsheetId'))
        print('spreadsheetUrl:', response.get('spreadsheetUrl'))
```

The code run successfully and created a new spreadsheet on the service account that I have created above, but when I open the spreadsheetUrl on my browser using the email that I have been granted like step number 5 and 7 like above, I got Access Denied, I'm seeing a screen like this which is mean I don't have access to the spreadsheet.

[image]

Isn't I already given my email access on the service account like step number 5 and 7 above?, So why my email still don't have permission to access the spreadsheet created by my service account?

Comment: If you need certain users to be able to access only sections of your Sheet, you should follow the steps from this G Suite Learning Center article "Protect content in a spreadsheet" [link](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308980).

Comment: Hi @JeffreyD. , I even can not access the spreadsheet that created by the service account.

Comment: If my understanding of your situation is correct, I think that in your setting, the added user can see and manage the created service account. But, in this case, it seems that the Spreadsheet created by the service account cannot be directly retrieved by the added user. In this case, how about the following 2 patterns? 1. Share the Spreadsheet with the user account. By this, you can access to the Spreadsheet created by the service account.

Comment: 2. If you are using Google Workspace, you can do "[Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)". If your account is Gmail account, please use the pattern 1. As another method, when you share a folder in your Google Drive with the service account, you can directly create the Spreadsheet in your folder by the service account. By this, you can see the created Spreadsheet in your Google Drive. If my comments were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

I grant my email permission to the created spreadsheet using bellow snippet of code:

```
def update_spreadsheet_permission(drive_service, spreadsheet_id, type, role, email_address):
    new_file_permission = {
        'type': type,
        'role': role,
        'emailAddress': email_address,
    }

    permission_response = drive_service.permissions().create(
        fileId=spreadsheet_id, body=new_file_permission).execute()

    return permission_response
```

So far the code can grant permission to emails with **role** `read` and `write`. But the code can't change the spreadsheet **type** to `owner` yet.